# Correctly type generic interface for forwardRef props

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, react-forwardref

I have seen a lot of answers on Stack Overflow about how to type forward refs in React, and whilst some of the answers work for certain parts of my application, in this case none of them do.

I am using React Native and return a View component wrapped by forwardRef. I have managed to type the ref parameter, but I can't seem to create a props interface that will make the TS compiler happy. What's strange to me about the error I get is that typing the props interface causes an error to be thrown when passing the ref down to the component, but as I say, the ref is already typed. Here is where I've got to:

```js
import React, { forwardRef, ReactNode, Ref } from 'react';
import { View as RNView } from 'react-native';

export type X = unknown;
export type ViewPropsType<P> = { [key: string]: P };
export type ViewRefType = Ref<ReactNode> | ReactNode;

const View = forwardRef<ViewRefType, ViewPropsType<X>>((props, ref) => (
    <RNView ref={ref} {...props} />
));

View.displayName = 'View';

export default View;
```

The TS compiler highlights an and error here `ref={ref}` when I change the props interface from type of `any` to the one above:

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(props: ViewProps | Readonly<ViewProps>): View', gave the following error.
    Type 'ForwardedRef<ViewRefType>' is not assignable to type 'LegacyRef<View> | undefined'.
      Type 'MutableRefObject<ViewRefType>' is not assignable to type 'LegacyRef<View> | undefined'.
        Type 'MutableRefObject<ViewRefType>' is not assignable to type 'RefObject<View>'.
          Types of property 'current' are incompatible.
            Type 'ViewRefType' is not assignable to type 'View | null'.
              Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'View | null'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(props: ViewProps, context: any): View', gave the following error.
    Type 'ForwardedRef<ViewRefType>' is not assignable to type 'LegacyRef<View> | undefined'.ts(2769)
```

How can I type this without using any?

Comment: Seem that you need to use `useRef`. AFAIK you need to create another one ref to use it as a `ref` in `RNView`. `const newRef=useRef(null)` and then `ref={newRef} works`

Comment: Ok thanks @captain-yossarian, but then what do I do with the ref that I pass in to forwardRef? If I use your solution it is unused..

Comment: I think you should not wrap View into forwardRef. What do you want to achieve?